# Plugin on Create of Phone Call not firing for Distribute Campaign Activity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We have a plugin registered on Create for Phonecall which triggers fine when I create via the UI or from within another plugin.  However, it never fires when Phonecall records are created as part of a Campaign Activity (bulk operation).

I've found an MSDN forum post that discussed registering in the child pipeline but this is no use for CRM 2011.

Can anyone confirm if this is expected behaviour and if possible what messages I could register for as a workaround.  Minimising changes to the existing plugin code would be a bonus.

Comment: Hi, Have you try registering in create message of entity Campaign Activity. I never try just a guess.

Comment: Activities don't get created until you Distribute which is after the Campaign Activity has been created.  I'd prefer to stick with triggering on phonecall creation if possible.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm just not sure I believe it.  You have a plugin that executes on the Create of a Phonecall entity just fine, but doesn't execute on the Create of a Phonecall entity, if the entity is created as part of a Campaign Activity,  (also never worked with Campaigns, so that could be my issue as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin was registered in Stage 10 Pre-Validation.  Registering in Pre-Operation or Post-Operation and it fires correctly on create and importantly for us distribute campaign activity.